# login page not linking to spring security

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring, spring-security

I am a beginner in web development and below is my login page code (Developing in Spring Boot):

login.html

```
<div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
          <button>create</button>
          <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form">
          <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
          <button>login</button>
          <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

login.css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
body {
  background: #76b852; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #76b852, #8DC26F);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
```

login.js

```
$('.message a').click(function(){
   $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

I want to add this custom login page instead of spring secuity login page:

So I did

```
public void copnfigure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("login.html").permitAll();

}
```

But at start still spring security login page only comes.I know there is something wrong in my login page(login.html) but could not figure out what is it?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem. Someone else can hopefully explain but it worked when I changed name from login.jsp in my case to something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loginPage` method expects URL mapping to show login form, not file name to render.

```
public void copnfigure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}
```

And now you need a controller:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

Here, `login` refers to `login.html`.

You can take a look at [the guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).